# Vertically align text next to (not in) a table

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

There are plenty of questions about vertically aligning text ***within*** a table. I wan't to make text to the ***left of*** a table vertically aligned to the top:

```
I want this text aligned to top:
\begin{tabular}{lll} 
     1. & First step &\\
     2. & Second step &\\
     3. & Go back & Step 1\\\\
     \hline\\
     4. & Can't get here & Error.
\end{tabular}
```

This is what the above LaTeX looks like:
[image]

Is there a way to make the "I want this text aligned to top" be aligned to the top instead of the vertical center of the table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add option `[t]` to `tabular` for its position:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
I want this text aligned to top:
\begin{tabular}[t]{lll} % <--- observe `t`
     1. & First step &\\
     2. & Second step &\\
     3. & Go back & Step 1\\\\
     \hline\\
     4. & Can't get here & Error.
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: oof that was fast

Comment: @jsbibra, oh thihs is so simple question ...

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for @Zarko!

Answer (score 3):

As said by Zarko, the solution to that question is to use the key `t` of the environment `{tabular}` but, for information, I add this answer to show that with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, there is also a key `baseline` to choice the row of the alignment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
I want this text aligned to the second row:
\begin{NiceTabular}{lll}[baseline=2]
     1. & First step &\\
     2. & Second step &\\
     3. & Go back & Step 1\\\\
     \hline\\
     4. & Can't get here & Error.
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz.

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 0):

simplicity as our elite member Zarko said

[image]

```
    \begin{tabular}[]{lll} 
    I want this text aligned to top:&   1. & First step \\
                                    &   2. & Second step \\
                                    &   3. & Go back Step 1\\
                            \cline{2-3}
                                    &   4. & Can't get here Error.
    \end{tabular}
```

Comment: I think a `\cmidrule` would look better.